# Indesign small subheading graphic library option?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there a way to design a subheading (fancy font, lines and small icons) that I could reuse again and again? Sort of like a clipart/small template library?

(I'm brand new to using InDesign. I figure there's gotta be a way people stick to a certain look.)

Answer (score 1):

Found it under Library and dragging my items into it and pulling them back out as needed.